# After creating a new row in a table using jquery .append() and click this new created row jquery is not working

Tags: html, jquery, django

In my code when I click on a  of a table, for every tr a corresponding page is open using jquery. But problem is after calling ajax when I add a new tr  by using jquery .append() method new tr is added at the end of the table but jquery click event is not working for newly added row. It need to refresh the whole page.

In this back-end I use django.

My jquery code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add_student_submit_btn').click(function() {
      image = document.getElementById('student_image').files[0];
      name = $('input[name = student_name]').val();
      email = $('input[name = student_email]').val();
      phone = $('input[name = student_phone]').val();
      formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image',image);
      formData.append('fullname',name);
      formData.append('email',email);
      formData.append('phone',phone);
      formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken',$('input[name = csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());
      $.ajax({
        url: {% url 'ajax.addstudents' %},
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          markup = '<tr scope="row" data-student-id="'+ data.id + '"class="students_row">';
          markup += '<td><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/' + data.image + '" alt="" class="student_img_table"></td>';
          markup += '<td>' +  data.fullname +'</td>';
          markup += '<td>' +  data.email +'</td>';
          markup += '<td>' +  data.phone +'</td>';
          markup += '<td>' +  '5' +'</td>';
          markup += '</tr>';

          tableBody = $("#student_table");
          tableBody.append(markup);
          $('#add_student_model').modal('hide');
        }
      });
    });

    $('.students_row').click(function(){
      id = $(this).attr('data-student-id');
      location.replace("/profile/"+id);
    });

  </script>
```

And here is my Html

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-hover" >
        <thead>
          <th scope="col">Image</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone</th>
          <th scope="col">Rating</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="student_table">
          {% for student in studets %}
          <tr scope="row" data-student-id="{{ student.id }}" class="students_row">

            <td><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ student.image.url }}" alt="" class="student_img_table"></td>
            <td>{{ student.fullname }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.rating }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}

        </tbody>

      </table>

    </div>
  </section>
<div class="add_student_div bg-success d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i class="fas fa-plus text-white fa-lg"></i></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="add_student_model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Add Student" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="">Add New Student</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="add_student_form"class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Student image</label>
            <input type="file" name="student_image" value="" id="student_image" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Student Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="student_name" value="" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Student email</label>
            <input type="email" name="student_email" value="" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Student phone</label>
            <input type="phone" name="student_phone" value="" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add_student_submit_btn">Add Student</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I highly recommend the use of [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for this application.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo {% for student in studets %}. 
Should be {% for student in students %}.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your click() event is defined outside your success callback on your ajax request. This cause the listener of the click to be defined before your new html is added because the success callback is called after.

```
$('.students_row').click(function(){
  id = $(this).attr('data-student-id');
  location.replace("/profile/"+id);
});
```

You need to set the clickevent inside the success callback of your Ajax request.

I would do something like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: {% url 'ajax.addstudents' %},
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      markup = '<tr scope="row" data-student-id="'+ data.id + '"class="students_row">';
      markup += '<td><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/' + data.image + '" alt="" class="student_img_table"></td>';
      markup += '<td>' +  data.fullname +'</td>';
      markup += '<td>' +  data.email +'</td>';
      markup += '<td>' +  data.phone +'</td>';
      markup += '<td>' +  '5' +'</td>';
      markup += '</tr>';

      tableBody = $("#student_table");
      tableBody.append(markup);
      $('#add_student_model').modal('hide');

      $('.students_row').click(function(){
      id = $(this).attr('data-student-id');
      location.replace("/profile/"+id);
    });

    }
  });
```